# generating pdf using mpdf how can I generate multiple pdf in PHP

Tags: php, mpdf, generate

I am using the mpdf library for generating the pdf, how can I generate multiple pdf using this library.

```
              include '../libs/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';
                      
                      for ($i=1; $i<count($sheetData); $i++) {
                      $name = $sheetData[$i][0];
                      $fName = $sheetData[$i][1];
                      $rollNo = $sheetData[$i][2];
                      $dept = $sheetData[$i][3];
                      $sessionType = $sheetData[$i][4];
                      $semester = $sheetData[$i][5];
                      $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => [290, 236]]);
                      $stylesheet = file_get_contents('../assets/css/style.css');
                      $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
                      ob_end_clean();
                      $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p> My Layout </p>')

                      $filename = time().'.pdf';
                      $mpdf->Output($filename ,'D');
                      unset($mpdf);
                      }
```

Only one file is generated instead of multiple, How can I generate multiple files.

Comment: What is the current behaviour? You need to provide more details. This code example should work as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Destroy the `$mpdf` object after you call the output. Simply `unset($mpdf);`.

Comment: Added this line after the output but did not work. Any other sol?