# php mpdf use in cicle FOR

Tags: php, mpdf

Good day !

I use mpdf in a loop

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$path_html= __DIR__.'/html/';
$path_pdf= __DIR__.'/pdf/';
$amount_file=10;
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
if (!file_exists($path_pdf)) {mkdir($path_pdf, 0755, true);}
function random_html($dir = 'html')
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}
$alphanum = 'abxzrmhtuiops123456789';

for ($amount_file_count=1; $amount_file_count <= $amount_file; $amount_file_count++) {

    $rand_file_name = substr(str_shuffle($alphanum), 2, 10) ;
    $html_file = file_get_contents(random_html());
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_file);
    $mpdf->Output($path_pdf . $rand_file_name . '.pdf');
    echo $amount_file;
}
```

When create next pdf add old  null page, Why? How do this correct? How correct FOR cicle ?

Comment: Have you tried moving `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();` inside the `for`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mPDF - How to create multiple PDFs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533081/mpdf-how-to-create-multiple-pdfs)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$path_html= __DIR__.'/html/';
$path_pdf= __DIR__.'/pdf/';
$amount_file=10;
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
if (!file_exists($path_pdf)) {mkdir($path_pdf, 0755, true);}
function random_html($dir = 'html')
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}
$alphanum = 'abxzrmhtuiops123456789';
for ($amount_file_count=1; $amount_file_count <= $amount_file; $amount_file_count++) {
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $rand_file_name = substr(str_shuffle($alphanum), 2, 10);
    $html_file = file_get_contents(random_html());
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_file);
    $mpdf->Output($path_pdf . $rand_file_name . '.pdf');
    echo $amount_file;
}
```

Comment: To be helpful to others, please explain your answer. In all this code, it is quite hard to spot what has changed. Also, remove the unrelated code for the example to be more readable and concise.